# Custom reflection method for setting field

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap, immutability

I'm fairly new to using reflection and am currently trying to implement a custom reflection util for setting fields. 
Looking at springboots ReflectionsTestUtils, I've got a mild understanding of how the setFields is done. I'm currently trying to implement that by taking an Object and an ImmutableMap as parameters.

The thought is to match the Field/Key value from the hashmap with a field that exists in the object. I understand the overall idea but the method i’ve tried implementing doesn’t seem work for retrieving the field from the map and comparing the one in the object.

My question is: 
Is there a more effiecient way to achieve this than what I have tried implementing below?

Not sure if i'm heading the right way here and would appreciate all the tips given:

```
    public static void setField(Object object, ImmutableMap<String, Object> map)
  throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
      if (object instanceof Object) {
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field aField : fields) {
         for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
          if (entry.getKey() instanceof Object) {
           String value = entry.getKey();
           checkPrimitiveValue(aField, object, value);
         }
        }
       }
    }
```

}

```
   private static void checkPrimitiveValue(Field field, Object object, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
// Find out Primitive and parse the string to correct value
if (field.getType() == boolean.class) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(object, Boolean.parseBoolean(value));
} else if (field.getType() == long.class) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(object, Long.parseLong(value));
} else if (field.getType() == int.class) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(object, Integer.parseInt(value));
} else if (field.getType() == double.class) {
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(object, Double.parseDouble(value));
} else { // String is used
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.set(object, value);
}
```

}

Comment: and the question is?

Answer (score 1):

The test:

```
 if (object instanceof Object)
```

is useless, except in the case where object is null, so here is a better way to write it:

```
 if (object != null)
```

You're assigning every key in the map to every field of the object. I guess you wanted to do something like:

```
    public static void setField(Object object, ImmutableMap<String, Object> map)
  throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        if (object != null) {
            Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

            for (Field aField: fields) {
                Object value = map.get(aField.getName());
                assignValue(aField, object, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I don't get why you're passing assuming that the values in the map are Strings (the static type is Object).

```
private static void assignValue(Field field, Object object, Object value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
            NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if (field.getType().isPrimitive())
        if (value == null) {
            value = defaultValue(field.getType());
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            value = parseValue(field.getType(), (String)value);
        }
    }
    field.set(object, value);
}
```

Default value of a primitive type:

```
private static Object defaultValue(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz == boolean.class) {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    } else if (clazz == char.class) {
        return (char)0;
    } else if (clazz == byte.class) {
        return (byte)0;
    } else if (clazz == short.class) {
        return (short)0;
    } else if (clazz == int.class) {
        return 0;
    } else if (clazz == long.class) {
        return 0L;
    } else if (clazz == float.class) {
        return 0F;
    } else if (clazz == double.class) {
        return 0.0;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a primitive type");
    }
}
```

Conversion from a string to a primitive type (I don't get why you're doing it, but here it is):

```
private static Object parseValue(Class<?> type, String s) {
    if (type == boolean.class) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(s);
    } else if (type == char.class) {
        return (char)Integer.parseInt(s);
    } else if (type == byte.class) {
        return Byte.valueOf(s);
    } else if (type == short.class) {
        return Short.valueOf(s);
    } else if (type == int.class) {
        return Integer.valueOf(s);
    } else if (type == long.class) {
        return Long.valueOf(s);
    } else if (type == float.class) {
        return Float.valueOf(s);
    } else if (type == double.class) {
        return Double.valueOf(s);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a primitive type");
    }
}
```